# This is Admin Login code in PHP, when i run the code, it does not load the Page that I want

Tags: php

```
<?php
//start the session
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

@mysql_select_db(fcs)
  or die("Unable to select Database");

//check if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $msg="";

  //VALIDATE form information
  if(empty($_POST['uname'])){
    $msg="Please enter your username.";
  }

  if(empty($_POST['upass'])){
    $msg .="Please enter your password.";
  }



  //check length of password
  if(strlen($_POST['upass']) > 6){
    $msg .="Invalid password.";
  }

  if(empty($msg)){


    $sql = "SELECT uname,upass FROM administrator WHERE user ='".$_POST['uname']."'";
    $sql .= "AND password ='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";

    if(!$res = mysql_query($sql)){
      $msg.=mysql_error();
    }else{
      //user exists in system, set the session variables
      if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
         // the user name and password match,
          $_SESSION['uname'] = $row['uname'];
          $_SESSION['upass'] = $_POST['upass'];

          //Now go to the main page
          header('location../admin.php');
        }
      }else{
        $msg = "Your login details did not match";
      }//end numrows check
    }//end res check
  }


}//end submit check
?>
```

Note:

I want to load the (admin.php) Page , if the user name and password was correct else
just disply out  a message:

Comment: Where’s the message and what is your question?

Comment: why is the redirect to the admin-page in a loop?

Comment: Concatenating unescaped $_POST variables into a MySQL query string is huge security issue - http://xkcd.com/327/.  At a minimum consider using PDO and prepared statements: http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 3):

the header-Function should be used like this:

```
header('Location: ../admin.php');
```

And even better would be if you specified the full absolute URL like this:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/admin.php');
```

That's because the [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30) requires it to be an absolute URI (although most browsers support relative URL's too):

```
Location = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
```

Answer (score 0):

Your location header should be:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/admin.php');
```

and you need to start the session at the top of the script using:

```
session_start();
```

That session start code should be at the start of every page that needs access to the $_SESSION variables.